# Can you tell in vertex shader whether data was sent with glDrawArrays() or glDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance()

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have 2 overloaded `draw()` functions, one of them draws with `glDrawArrays()` and the other one with `glDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance()`, Im wondering if its somehow possible to tell in vertex shader which drawing method was used.

If I could somehow tell I would only need an if() statement in my vertex shader to take care of the cases respectively but if its not possible Ill have to use different vertex shaders.

**Something Ive thought of:**
Maybe there is a way to check if gl_InstanceID or gl_baseInstance is a valid value but most likely there is not.

Comment: The "draw call" is not an OpenGL state or even a state that can be retrieved in-shader. What's wrong with a uniform variable and setting the uniform before the draw call?

Comment: Thats actually a very good idea.

Comment: [Render Doc?](https://renderdoc.org/builds)

Comment: Why do you even need to know in the vertex shader? As per the spec, drawing without instancing is equivalent to drawing with an instance count of 1, and `gl_InstaceID` is guaranteed to be 0. So what do you need a distinction for?

Comment: @derhass With my newfound knowledge I believe that the question in and of it self is pretty dumb. I wanted my vertex shader to handle `glDrawArrays()` call differently from `glDrawArraysInstancedBaseInstance()`. The best way to do this is probably to have a different shader for different type of draw call, but since my program is very very small I can just send an int uniform with each draw call and then have a if - else to further process the data differently.